# Android - получение постоянного токена устройства

Tags: android

Помогите разобраться с тем как получить токен устройства, которым я могу пользоваться на протяжении длительного времени на стороне сервера.

Comment: Загляните сюда: https://habrahabr.ru/post/229039/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужен уникальный ID устройства, который гарантированно не поменяется со временем, используйте [Secure.ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```